# Using Import-CSV in Powershell, ignoring commented lines

Tags: powershell

I think that I must be missing something obvious because I'm trying to use Import-CSV to import CSV files that have commented out lines (always beginning with a # as the first character) at the top of the file, so the file looks like this:

```
#[SpecialCSV],,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#Version,1.0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#[Table],,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header7,...
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Data6,Data7,...
```

I'd like to ignore those first 5 lines, but still use Import-csv to get the rest of the information nicely in to Powershell.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSV has no notion of "comments" - it's just flat data. You'll need to use `Get-Content` and inspect each line. If a line starts with `#`, ignore it, otherwise process it.

If you're OK with using a temp file:

```
Get-content special.csv |where-object{!$_.StartsWith("#")}|add-content -path $(join-path -path $env:temp -childpath "special-filtered.csv");
$mydata = import-csv -path $(join-path -path $env:temp -childpath "special-filtered.csv");
remove-item -path $(join-path -path $env:temp -childpath "special-filtered.csv")
$mydata |format-table -autosize; #Just for illustration
```

Edit: Forgot about `convertfrom-csv`. It gets much simpler this way.

```
$mydata = Get-Content special.csv |
    Where-Object { !$_.StartsWith("#") } |
    ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple - just use **Select-String** to exclude commented lines with a regex, and pipe to **ConvertFrom-Csv**:

```
Get-Content <path to CSV file> | Select-String '^[^#]' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

The difference between **Import-Csv** and **ConvertTo-Csv** is that the former takes input from a file, and the latter takes pipeline input, otherwise they do the same thing - convert CSV data to an array of PSCustomObjects. So, by using **ConvertFrom-Csv** you can do this without modifying the CSV flie or using a temp file. You can assign the results to an array or pipe to a **Foreach-Object** block just as you'd do with **Import-Csv**:

```
$array = Get-Content <path to CSV file> | Select-String '^[^#]' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

or

```
Get-Content <path to CSV file> | Select-String '^[^#]' | ConvertFrom-Csv | %{
  <whatever you want do with the data>
}
```

Comment: No need for `Get-Content`. Simply do `Select-String '^[^#]' 'C:\path\to\the.csv' | ...`

Comment: The problem with that is that it adds the filename and line# info to the first property, so  you get a property named `<path>:6:Header1` and data like `<path>:<line #>:<value of first column>`. I don't see a way to suppress that info if you give **Select-String** a file argument rather than pipeline input (piping through `select Line` gives you string output, so **ConvertFrom-Csv** comes out null).

Comment: `... | % { $_.Line } | ...`

Comment: Oh, right! I confused myself with this one. I actually tried piping through `%{$_.Line}` but didn't bother trying to send that to **ConvertTo-Csv** because it produces string data. But my comment above is backwards - you *want* comma-separated string input for **ConvertFrom-Csv**, and `| select Line` doesn't work because it *doesn't* output strings... *duh!* In any case, you lose the simplicity if you have to do that - easier to type `gc` than `%{$_.Line}`.

Comment: I'd probably just to `(Get-Content foo) -notlike '#*' | ConvertFrom-Csv`. I never really saw the point in `Select-String`, somehow all the alternatives are easier to read and faster to write.

Answer (score 3):

If you feed convertfrom-csv csv data as an array of lines it seems to automatically filter out comments.  I frequently use convertfrom-csv this way but I haven't seen it documented.

```
cat  data.csv | convertfrom-csv      #skips commented lines automagically


("co1,col2,col3",  "abc,def,ghi", "#this,is,a,comment", "abc1,def1,ghi1")|convertfrom-csv


co1  col2 col3
---  ---- ----
abc  def  ghi 
abc1 def1 ghi1
```

However, the following will not skip comments:

```
"co1,col2,col3
abc,def,ghi
#this,is,a,comment
abc1,def1,ghi1
"|convertfrom-csv


co1   col2 col3
---   ---- ----
abc   def  ghi 
#this is   a   
abc1  def1 ghi1
```

Comment: `Import-Csv` ignores "#" comments too.

Answer (score 1):

Where-object will work after import-csv as well. You just have to reference the first column from csv in the clause.
e.g.:

```
$EscapeCharacter = '#'
$FilteredData = Import-Csv -Path "$($Home)\Documents\sample.csv" -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding UTF8 | Where-Object {$_.coll1 -notlike "$EscapeCharacter*"}
```

The sample of tab delimited csv:

```
coll1   coll2
#Kotehulky  SomeValue
Cakovice    OtherValue
```